# Calculate percentiles from number of occurrences

Tags: google-sheets, statistics

I have a set of possible values, and for each, how many times they appeared in a dataset. How do I calculate percentiles from these ? The `PERCENTILE` only takes in a complete dataset, i.e. each occurrence listed individually, but I don't have this. Rather, I only have the appearance count of each possible value.

An example spreadsheet would be something like this :

```
Value  |   Occurrence count
2      |    123
3      |    39
4      |    273
5      |    55
6      |    90
```

[Found here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wZ90VlZqHCBkek9wARShb33oS2gSryH0aJ2I35p9gXU/copy)

And for example here the 75th percentile is more or less exactly at 4, which I can demonstrate with the opposite process than the one I am looking for, i.e. given a value, find which percentile it covers :

- Number of occurrences of values of 4 and under : 123+39+273 = 435
- Total number of all values in data set : 123+39+273+55+90 = 580
- 435/580 = 0.75

=> So values of 4 and under represent 75% of the population of values.

I want a math formula that, similarly to `PERCENTILE`, takes a percentile as input and returns which value (even if not one in the list of possible values but in between two of them) corresponds to that percentile. Except `PERCENTILE` also takes as input the entire data set, where I only have the table of count of occurrences to provide.

In the example sheet you will find an attempt where I tried to recreate the dataset manually by repeating the values as many times as I know they occurred in the original dataset - but I couldn't do this in one formula. This is discussed [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/163082/use-sequence-and-arrayformula-together).

Comment: Added a simple example.

Comment: A spreadsheet can easily be created from my example if needed. I clarified what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, it would seem like writing those messages is at least as much work as creating a small example, which, for a volunteer with a helpful idea, I still recommend to do - while I look at how to create anonymous spreadsheets (which is also work)

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Your spreadsheet requires consent to access it; it is better to allow full access, or at least "view" access (so that a user can make their own copy for development/testing.

Comment: FYI, the Database Adminstrators forum has a post (with an accepted answer) called:  [Calculating percentile using counts of occurrences](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/160933). StackOverflow also has a post [percentiles from counts of values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25070086/1330560).

Comment: StackOverflow has a question identical to yours (different data): [Calculating percentiles in Excel with "buckets" data instead of the data list itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18326453/1330560), The answer is by @pnuts who enjoys a very healthy reputation however the answer was not accepted and has no votes. The logic seems OK to me BUT it was 50 years ago when I last studied this subject and I don't wish to misled you by saying the answer is "correct" (sorry, pnuts!). I suggest that you read the question and answer very carefully and make your own judgement.

Comment: Thank you. These are definitely the same questions as far as the theory is concerned, however none of the solutions involve Google Spreadsheets, but rather other languages which I don't understand. One involves Excel but suggests more like an algorithm (you search upwards through the cumulative totals for each value until you find the one that covers at least your percentile interpreted as a percentage of the total). Unless there is a way to perform such a search ?