# Use SEQUENCE and ARRAYFORMULA together

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create sequences of cells of repeating digits using the function `SEQUENCE`. However I also want to gather them all in one big array using `ARRAYFORMULA` and then `FLATTEN`, but it doesn't seem to work the way I expect.

Here an example of where I use the formula `SEQUENCE(1,Repeat,Value,0)` to create output sequences for each individual lines. I want to produce all of these lines at once in one formula and then `FLATTEN` them all in one big array.

```
Value  Repeat  Output (over multiple columns)
 2       3       2   2   2                    
 3       2       3   3
 4       3       4   4   4
```

So I tried to write `ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(1,Array_of_Repeats,Array_of_Values,0))` but this only produces the following output :

```
2
3
4
```

over a single column (no further columns are produced), so only the starting column ...

See example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wZ90VlZqHCBkek9wARShb33oS2gSryH0aJ2I35p9gXU/copy)

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayFormula()` won't work as expected when used with functions that by default accept arrays.

Try something like this instead:

```
=arrayformula(split(rept(A2:A4&"❄️",B2:B4),"❄️"))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, it is very good, that. Have a vote. However I now hit the limit of 32000 characters allowed as a result of `REPT` ... I still like the snowflake though.

Comment: Try to replace the snowflake with any character that's not an emoji (as most of them have a length > 1) and see if that works.

Comment: No I mean I definitely have to repeat things a lot more than 32000 times

Comment: The max amount of columns is ~18k. How are you going to repeat something 32k+ times in the same row?

Comment: I don't plan to show the data, only to do some stats on it. So whatever huge arrays are returned here will directly be fed to a function within the same formula of the same cell.